# Create a new list with if statement in Python

Tags: python, arrays, if-statement

I have 4 list

```
list01 = [2,5,4,9,10,-3,5,5,3,-8,0,2,3,8,8,-2,-4,0,6]
list02 = [-7,-3,8,-5,-5,-2,4,6,7,5,9,10,2,13,-12,-4,1,0,5]
list03 = [2,-5,6,7,-2,-3,0,3,0,2,8,7,9,2,0,-2,5,5,6]
biglist = list01 + list02 + list03
```

How can I create a new list called "newlist02" that contains the elements of "biglist" that are greater than 0?

Here is what I tried.

```
ct = 0
for xval in biglist:
    if 0 < xval:
        ct += 1  # Adds 1 to ct; same as ct = ct + 1
print(ct)        # print out the total number of elements that greater than 0. 


newlist02 = 36*[0]    # create a new list with 36 "0"s
for xval in biglist:
    if 0 < xval:
        newlist02[xval] = xval # Adds 1 to ct; same as ct = ct + 1
print(newlist02)
```

the output I got is:
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 0, 0, 13, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

How can I only contain the number which are larger than 0?

Comment: Initiate a new list, loop through list1 and for each element, if the element is > 0, append it to the new list.

Comment: use `filter`, or a list comprehension. No need for explicit loops.

Comment: I just posted what I tried

Answer (score 1):

don't mix values and indexes.

Wait. Don't use indexes at all. And don't pre-build a list. Just use list comprehension to filter out negative values

```
list01 = [2,5,4,9,10,-3,5,5,3,-8,0,2,3,8,8,-2,-4,0,6]
list02 = [-7,-3,8,-5,-5,-2,4,6,7,5,9,10,2,13,-12,-4,1,0,5]
list03 = [2,-5,6,7,-2,-3,0,3,0,2,8,7,9,2,0,-2,5,5,6]
biglist = list01 + list02 + list03

newlist02 = [x for x in biglist if x>0]
```

result:

```
[2, 5, 4, 9, 10, 5, 5, 3, 2, 3, 8, 8, 6, 8, 4, 6, 7, 5, 9, 10, 2, 13, 1, 5, 2, 6, 7, 3, 2, 8, 7, 9, 2, 5, 5, 6]
```

note that you don't need to add elements to filter them. Use `itertools.chain` to avoid building the big list:

```
import itertools

newlist02 = [x for x in itertools.chain(list01,list02,list03) if x>0]
```

result is identical as above, but we saved the creation of `biglist` if we don't need it.